# How to improve IDEA performance?

Tags: performance, ide, intellij-idea, pycharm

I like IDEs from JetBrains most of other IDEs. I often use IDEA and PyCharm And while I work with them, I spend much time on waiting IDEA's different tasks.
So is there are any tips how to improve IDEA and PyCharm performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have performance problems with IntelliJ IDEA, refer to the [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235) and [thread dump](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544899) instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, that IDE is too slow before.

Then, I try to do some changes...

**On Setting Page : File - Settings...**

[image: Settings]

On Appereance, this is my configuration :

[image: Appereance]

On Plugins, try deactivate unused plugins :

[image: Plugins]

On Updates, I turn off updates :

[image: Updates]

**[Configuring JVM options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html)**

I use 64 Bit Windows 7.

I go to : `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4\bin`

Open `idea64.exe.vmoptions` using text editor, and change values of `-Xmx` and `-Xms`

This is my new `idea64.exe.vmoptions` config :

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Description (Official):

**-Xmx**    Limits the maximum memory heap size that the JVM can allocate for running IntelliJ IDEA. Default value depends on the platform. If you are experiencing slowdowns, you may want to increase this value, for example, to set the value to 2048 megabytes, change this option to -Xmx2048m.

**-Xms**    Specifies the initial memory allocated by the JVM for running IntelliJ IDEA. Default value depends on the platform. It is usually set to about half of the maximum allowed memory (-Xmx), for example, -Xms1024m.

Answer (score 0):

Change memory sizes in

```
<YOUR IDEA HOME>/bin/idea.vmoptions
```

or in

```
<YOUR IDEA HOME>/bin/idea64.vmoptions
```

if your IDEA is running on a 64 bit machine.